# Commerce 2 — Guest checkout error: no customer email address exists on this cart

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce2, ecommerce, payment

I'm having a problem with checking out as a Guest.

Below is the design so you can see what I'm talking about...

[image: Screenshot of 2 login forms in a checkout process — 1 saying 'Already Registered?' and the other 'Guest Checkout']

Although I'm entering an email address in the Guest Checkout email field — when I get to the payment page it won't allow payments to process due to an error pop-up message stating "no customer email address exists on this cart."

[image]

Both login options (on the Checkout index template) are using separate `<form>`'s so I know that isn't an issue. I've tried different email addresses and still nothing.

I've also checked the Craft Commerce GitHub repo templates and can see the action and redirects are the same as what I've got in mine.

Has anyone else came across this problem before and knows how to fix it?

Is it worthwhile switching to the new template structure (email > account > etc etc)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to the new template structure fixed the issue I had regarding the email not being recognised/saved.